# A triple throw of a coin - probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We are throwing a coin three times. Let's T and H mean tails and heads. We can get 3 events such as: $A_1=\{(H,T,T)\}, A_2=\{(T,H,T)\}$ and $A_3=\{(T,T,H)\}$. What is the mutual part of $A_1$ and $A_2$ ($A_1 \cap A_2$), for example? Is it $\{(H,H,T)\}$ and $\{(T,T,T)\}?$

I took this question from a task which asked to describe an event when there'll be at least one heads using only $A_1,A_2,A_3$. And the answer was $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3$.

I'll be glad for the correction and the explanation even if I'm right or not.

Comment: I think "O" means "either T or H". If so, draw a picture of the sample space showing all eight possibilities, and make a Venn diagram outlining the sets you care about.